# Generic repository - How to access property of <T>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm wondering if it is possible to access a property of  and use .FirstOrDefaultAsync.
My attempt is below:

If it is possible, what do I need to change in the code?
Thank you in advance.

```
    public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly ODWEApiDbContext _DbContext;

        public BaseRepository(ODWEApiDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _DbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public virtual async Task<T> GetByPersonalId(int entityId)
        {
            return await _DbContext.Set<T>().OfType<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PersonalId == entityId);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the only necessary code you've provided:

```
where T : class

// and

_DbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PersonalId == entityId);

//.OfType<T>() is not necessary
```

If we were to write it more explicitly it would be:

```
_DbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync((object x) => x.PersonalId == entityId);
```

As the *default* for `class` is `object` and [object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-7.0) does not have a property named `PersonalId`.

So you need to updated your constraint of `T` to include either an interface that has that property or a class that has that property:

```
// abstract not required, just recommended
public abstract class EntityBase
{
  public int PersonalId { get; set; }
}

where T : EntityBase


// or


public interface class IEntityBase
{
  int PersonalId { get; }
}

where T : IEntityBase, class
```

AND then you have to make sure that any T you do want to use must derive from which you've chosen:

```
public class Person : EntityBase
{
  // ...
}

public class Person : IEntityBase 
{
 // ...
}
```

So finally we'd have

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : IEntityBase, class
{
  // ...

  public virtual async Task<T> GetByPersonalId(int entityId)
  {
    return await _DbContext
      .Set<T>()
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.PersonalId == entityId);
  }
}
```

Where

```
(x => x.PersonalId == entityId)

// would written more explicitly would be

((IEntityBase x) => x.PersonalId = entityId)
```

When using a derived type:

```
public class PersonRepository : BaseRepository<Person> 
where T : IEntityBase, class
{
}
```

The Predicate (`x => bool`) can only use the properties of `IEntityBase`, the DBSet returned by `Set<T>()` will be the derived type in your instantiated repository:

```
using (var personRepo = new PersonRepository(db))
{
  Person person = personRepo.GetByPersonalId(1);
  // or
  var person = personRepo.GetByPersonalId(1);
}
```

Comment: If you were writing it more explicitly it would be `_DbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefaultAsync((T x) => x.PersonalId == entityId);`, but `T` would implicitly be `object`.

Comment: This is pretty much it. Normally you would use a common column as "Id" then if you typically wanted to follow a naming convention in the database of things like "PersonId", "OrderId", etc. in the tables, just annotate your entities with the `[Key, Column("PersonId")]` etc above the `Id` property declared in the entity. Though I highly discourage developers from adopting the Generic Repository pattern with EF. It adds nothing to what is already available with the `DbContext` and `DbSet` and only serves to handcuff the flexibility of any application using it.

Comment: @Enigmativity wouldn't `(T x)` be less explicit than `(object x)`? Or maybe I should have said verbose?

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I think it's more explicit as `T` could be more explicit than `object` such as `struct` or some sub-type.