# Unity Passing ScriptableObject Types to Generic Function

Tags: unity-game-engine, variables, generics, types

I've found myself duplicating functions across scripts and am trying to reduce this code and not repeat myself by using GENERICS. I'm still new to working in a strictly typed language and find it a bit frustrating at times. I'm working with Scriptable Objects of different types. Here is the situation I have:

Script A (for Characters)

```
public void doSomething(Character mySO){
  // WORKS!
  print(mySO.CharacterID);
  ...do the same stuff here with data from the Character mySO....
}
```

Script B (for Items)

```
public void doSomething(Item mySO){
  // WORKS!
  print(mySO.ItemID);
  ...do the same stuff here with data from the Item mySO...
}
```

In a separate utilities script I'd like to write the function once and use a generic to handle the type... but everything I do is failing....

```
public void doSomething<T>(T mySO){
   // Item newmySO;
   // print(newmySO.itemID); WORKS!

   // Character newmySO;
   // print(newmySO.CharacterID); WORKS!

   // T newmySO=(T)mySO;
   // print(newmySO.itemID); undefined;
   
   ...do the same stuff here with data from the Scriptable Object data...
}
```

not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I've read a ton of docs and tried many things. If I use a constraint on the generic it works, but then it gives me other problems since I have multiple types and scriptableobjects....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic repository - How to access property of <T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76640459/generic-repository-how-to-access-property-of-t)

Comment: No, constraints cause problems since I'm using scriptableobjects

Comment: If you have functions that do different things based on the type you are passing in, why would you want to consolidate them into a single method in the first place?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that `T` is `ScriptableObject` and it also doesn't know that `ScriptableObject` has a property called `itemID`.

Comment: sounds like your objects should probably rather have a common [**interface**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) which your method can consume .. like e.g. `public interface IIDProvider { string ID { get; } }`  and then you would append `where T : IIDProvider` after `<T>(T mySO)`

Comment: thanks derHugo - this is as far as I got but with classes? I read a base class would solve the problem and allow me to only use a single constraint - getting around the problems I was running into... but I'm unable to use base classes with SOs. I'm unfamiliar with interfaces though so will have to read up on those. @shingo the function does the exact same thing - to 2 different types of scriptableobjects